# Is .lib file required for applications with load time Dynamic linking?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

It says that in case you use **load time dynamic linking** with DLL it looks up functions entries and other things from a .lib file.

However I cannot find any information on whether this .lib file is required only at compile time or if it needs to be shipped with the program executable for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lib files are linked into final executable or DLL - so no, you don't need to ship Lib files to users of the application.

If you are building DLL you may provide lib file for your DLL to developers to simplify using of your DLL.

Comment: In case the .lib is not passed to other developers along with the dll is there still a way they could generate it or do something to get load time linking ?

Comment: @Allahjane yes, also it would be quite painful especially for C++ style classes. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131313. I doubt you'll find many people willing to do so (obviously it is not security measure as level of hacking required to get this info is very low).